# Kubelet on Windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes on Windows and connected it as a worker to a Linux master following the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/joining-windows-workers

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.03.1-ee-3
 API version:       1.37
 Go version:        go1.10.2
 Git commit:        b9a5c95
 Built:             Thu Aug 30 18:42:35 2018
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.03.1-ee-3
  API version:      1.37 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.2
  Git commit:       b9a5c95
  Built:            Thu Aug 30 18:56:49 2018
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.4",...}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.4",...}
```

kubectl config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://10.1.0.6:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

After running the start.ps1 script with the relevant arguments it connects to Kubernetes fine but doesn't resolve any service DNS:

kubectl get nodes

```
NAME              STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
dckazumstr        Ready     master    3d        v1.11.4
dckazunonprod01   Ready     <none>    31m       v1.11.4
dckazunonprod02   Ready     <none>    18h       v1.11.4
dckazuslave       Ready     <none>    39m       v1.11.4
```

kubectl get services

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
consul          ClusterIP   10.98.247.75    <none>        8500/TCP       1h
```

Output on the container has this:

```
Failed to resolve consul: lookup consul: no such host
```

The Linux slave is able to resolve the DNS fine:

```
ping consul
PING consul.default.svc.cluster.local (10.98.247.75) 56(84) bytes of data
```

Consul is just a test deployment as we already had it working with compose so know it *should* work.

Due to the errors I ran the component parts of the script manually and get the below errors when running start-kubelet.ps1

```
E1127 11:19:44.638355    5500 server.go:711] Kubelet needs to run as uid `0`. It is being run as -1
E1127 11:19:46.030649    5500 kubelet_network.go:102] Failed to ensure that nat chain KUBE-MARK-DROP exists: error creating chain "KUBE-MARK-DROP": executable file not found in %PATH%: 
E1127 11:19:46.056554    5500 helpers.go:735] eviction manager: failed to construct signal: "allocatableMemory.available" error: system container "pods" not found in metrics
```

Can anyone tell me if these are ok messages or if the DNS issue is caused by something else?

EDIT:
To show options for start.ps1

```
.\start.ps1 -ManagementIP 10.1.0.4 -ClusterCIDR 10.244.0.0/16 -ServiceCIDR 10.96.0.0/12 -KubeDnsServiceIP 10.96.0.10
```

To show these details are correct:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.96.0.0/12
```

kubectl cluster-info dump

```
--service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12"
```

kubectl get svc/kube-dns -n kube-system

```
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP 
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10
```

kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o wide

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE
default       consul-7cdfb788c4-cn7pm              1/1       Running   0          2d        10.244.2.60    dckazunonprod02   <none>
default       consul-7cdfb788c4-k4n4q              1/1       Running   0          2d        10.244.2.61    dckazunonprod02   <none>
default       consul-lin-77b87d549c-d5hrc          1/1       Running   0          2d        10.244.0.102   dckazumstr        <none>
default       consul-lin-77b87d549c-kg6ks          1/1       Running   0          2d        10.244.1.5     dckazuslave       <none>
kube-system   etcd-dckazumstr                      1/1       Running   1          5d        10.1.0.6       dckazumstr        <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dckazumstr            1/1       Running   1          5d        10.1.0.6       dckazumstr        <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dckazumstr   1/1       Running   1          5d        10.1.0.6       dckazumstr        <none>
kube-system   kube-dns-86c47599bd-kdbz6            3/3       Running   0          5d        10.244.1.2     dckazuslave       <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-j8lxq          1/1       Running   0          5d        10.1.0.6       dckazumstr        <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xpvl9          1/1       Running   0          5d        10.1.0.7       dckazuslave       <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-bbn2l                     1/1       Running   1          5d        10.1.0.7       dckazuslave       <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-z96b6                     1/1       Running   1          5d        10.1.0.6       dckazumstr        <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dckazumstr            1/1       Running   1          5d        10.1.0.6       dckazumstr
```

The issue is the same with CoreDNS, this was changed to rule out the DNS service being the issue.

Comment: Please show which options are you using when starting start.ps1 script.

Comment: Edited the question to show this information

Comment: Can you provide an output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`?

Comment: @Crou added this information

Comment: The link in the question is outdated. Please update.

Comment: This whole question is outdated...